# How to map Nullable<Ulid> (or any other nullable custom struct) in Entity Framework Core 5/6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Take the following Entity Framework Core entity class:

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    public Ulid Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Ulid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;
    public Ulid? CompanyId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Company? Company { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Note that the primary key is a non-nullable Ulid, which is a struct defined in [this 3rd party library](https://github.com/Cysharp/Ulid/) and allows for the generation of sortable unique identifiers outside of the database.

I am mapping the Ulid to a PostgreSQL `bytea` column in the Entity Framework `DbContext` as follows, in accordance with the library instructions [here](https://github.com/Cysharp/Ulid/#:%7E:text=Entity,it):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var bytesConverter = new UlidToBytesConverter();

    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // Don't use database-generated values for primary keys
        if (typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                .Property<Ulid>(nameof(IEntity.Id)).ValueGeneratedNever();
        }

        // Convert Ulids to bytea when persisting
        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.ClrType == typeof(Ulid) || property.ClrType == typeof(Ulid?))
            {
                property.SetValueConverter(bytesConverter);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class UlidToBytesConverter : ValueConverter<Ulid, byte[]>
{
    private static readonly ConverterMappingHints DefaultHints = new ConverterMappingHints(size: 16);

    public UlidToBytesConverter(ConverterMappingHints? mappingHints = null)
        : base(
                convertToProviderExpression: x => x.ToByteArray(),
                convertFromProviderExpression: x => new Ulid(x),
                mappingHints: DefaultHints.With(mappingHints))
    {
    }
}
```

This mapping works fine for non-nullable Ulids, but the `User.CompanyId` property cannot be mapped because it is nullable (which reflects the fact that a `User` optionally belongs to a `Company`). Specifically, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'User.CompanyId' could not be mapped because it is of type 'Nullable<Ulid>', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
...
```

Is it possible to map custom nullable struct types in EF Core 5/6 and, if so, how? I have spent a number of hours trawling the Entity Framework documentation, Google and Github, but have had no success in finding a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a significant amount of further experimentation, I discovered that the error message in my original question was ultimately a red herring and that using the `UlidToBytesConverter` inheriting from `ValueConverter` was all that was required!

The problem appears to have been caused by the fact that using a custom type as primary and foreign keys breaks EF Core's [convention-based mapping](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions#foreign-key) of foreign key properties (e.g. automatically mapping `CompanyId` to the `Company` navigation property). I can't find any documentation describing this behavior.

Accordingly, EF Core was trying to create a new property `CompanyId1` and for some reason the value converter was not being applied.

The solution was to add the `ForeignKey` attribute as to the `CompanyId` property as follows:

```cs
public class User : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Ulid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = default!;
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Company))]
    public Ulid? CompanyId { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Company? Company { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the processing order of properties and navigations, Entity Framework Core doesn't automatically process the optional `Ulid?` fields, and ends up creating shadow foreign keys leading to the mentioned problem.

Creating properties manually and applying the value converter at property level fixes the issue.

Something like the following solves the issue for all entity types without having to specify `[ForeignKey]` attribute manually.

```csharp
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    foreach (var ulidProperty in entityType.ClrType
                 .GetPublicInstanceProperties() // helper extension method
                 .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(Ulid) || x.PropertyType == typeof(Ulid?)))
    {
        if (ulidProperty.PropertyType == typeof(Ulid))
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                .Property<Ulid>(ulidProperty.Name)
                .HasConversion<UlidToBytesConverter>();
        }
        else
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                .Property<Ulid?>(ulidProperty.Name)
                .HasConversion<UlidToBytesConverter>();
        }
    }
}
```